# Weird Exceptions from Visual Studio in Workflow Foundation project

Tags: .net, wpf, workflow-foundation-4

I'm getting a "type or namespace name could not be found" exception when I try to create an instance of an activity. Target Framework is .Net4 (full profile)

The WF is defined as follows:

```
<Activity x:Class="MyApp.Workflow.MyWorkflow " ...>
```

It doesn't contain any activity code yet, just created it. My calling code:

```
using MyApp.Workflow;
MyWorkflow workflow = new MyWorkflow();
```

I made sure all dlls referenced in the workflow's xaml are referenced. Does anybody have an idea what else I could check?

**EDIT** - Tried the following :

- Add a new Activity to the project
- Go to any source code file and add a call to activity's constructor (with syntax highlighting and code completion - intellisense recognizes the type)
- Recompile

Result: The Type of the Workflow (MyApp.Workflow.**MyWorkflow**) is unknown.
When I do the same thing in another solution with exactly the same references, it works as it should.

Comment: Which type or namespace could not be found? `MyWorkflow`?

Comment: Sorry, `MyWorkflow` is the only class in the namespace `Workflow`. It
's `Workflow` that cannot be found. Few more facts : This Namespace contains only WF Xaml files. When I hit BUILD, the XAML is compiled into a g.cs file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found it, eventually. There seems to be a bug in the XAML-parser that causes this to happen. It can easily be reproduced:

- Create a WPF project
- Add a `WF` Activity to that project and place a call to that activity's constructor somewhere
- Press F6 and be happy
- Add `xmlns:xyz="clr-namespace:Namespace.That.Contains.Controls"` to your Window's code. If you don't feel like creating controls, just use the namespace the window is defined in.
- Press F6 and see how the activity can not be parsed anymore. If the activity is within a namespace that it spans, the namespace won't exist, otherwise the activity's type will not exist.

GodDammit, that cost me an entire day...

Answer (score 0):

Please do these steps

1. Clean Solution.
2. Build Solution.
3. Add reference.
4. Import namespace at workflow, bottom of your workflow designer.

Comment: What kind of namespace should I reference?